# Python - Evaluating two expressions in Pandas DataFrame and create new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
      id     TV  radio  newspaper  sales
0      1  230.1   37.8       69.2   22.1
1      2   44.5   39.3       45.1   10.4
2      3   17.2   45.9       69.3    9.3
```

I want to add two new columns, one is called "invested_amount" that is the sum of TV, radio and newspaper divided by sales. So, I made this:

```
new_data = (sales_csv
    .assign(invested_amount = lambda df: df['TV'] + df['radio'] + df['newspaper'] / df['sales'])
)
```

This line works fine, it create the colum with the new values, the problem is that after that, I want to add a new colum called "successful_campaign" that return a boolean value if invested_amount is less than 20 and the sum of TV, radio and newspaper is more than 15000.

I have this:

```
new_data = (sales_csv
    .assign(invested_amount = lambda df: df['TV'] + df['radio'] + df['newspaper'] / df['sales'])
    .assign(successful_campaign = lambda df: df['invested_amount'] < 20 & df['TV'] + df['radio'] + df['newspaper'] > 15000)
)
```

After add the invested_amount column, I add the new column evaluating this two conditions, but when I run the file it return this: `TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]` The thing is, if I remove the second condition and let the evaluation like this:

```
.assign(successful_campaign = lambda df: df['invested_amount'] < 20)
```

It works. So, the problem is evaluating the second condition but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

With the dataframe called `df`

```
df['successful_campaign'] = (df['invested_amount'] < 20) & ((df['TV'] + df['radio'] + df['newspaper']) > 15000)
```

should do you, also

```
df['invested_amount'] = (df['TV'] + df['radio'] + df['newspaper'] ) / df['sales']
```

would look a sight nicer

Comment: You should typically prefer taking advantage of pandas vectorization and try to avoid `lambda` when possible.